# Sirius radio location

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, antenna

Where do I find the sirius xm receiver in a 2014 silverado 1500?? I am getting an error message "no signal, signal may be blocked"? I want to check the antenna connection and I am having trouble getting to the raceiver.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The Sirius/XM receiver is built into the antenna just above the driver on the roof of the cab. It looks like this:

[image]

To gain access to the wiring on it, you have to pull the hood liner down.